# Component identification: fuse? and a mystery blob?

Tags: identification

I'm trying to reverse engineer an amplifier, and there's two components that I cannot identify. For context, it was made in 1973 so it's all quite vintage.

I think the first one might be some kind of fuse? There's two on the board, one between Vcc and GND, and one between the output and GND via a 10 ohm resistor. It's marked with the text 82/250, 250V maybe, with some kind of rating?

[image: Thing]

The other component is some kind of blobby thing that might be a capacitor or a coil? But if it's cap, there should be some kind of value marking, so I would expect more bands or some text?

[image: Blob]

EDIT: some more blob pictures, one from the other side, one from the top:

[image: Blob]

[image: Blob]

Comment: 82nF @ 250V mylar cap? The second item might be a PTC - thermistor. The Japanese were partial to using these. Most of that old stuff you can get schematics for on the web.

Comment: If the first component is connected between Vcc and ground, then it is certainly not a fuse : a fuse is basicaly a wire (or a very small resistor), so if yoy put a fuse between VCC and ground, you make a short circuit, so the fuse will blow imediatly. So there is no point of putting a fuse between VCC and ground, as it will be gone at once (excepted maybe as a strange way to detect if the device was ever used or not)

Comment: First one could be a polyphenylene cap. In that case it's most probably 82 picoFarad rather than a nano or micro farad.

Comment: Oh wow bit of a derp moment on the fuse. So yeah let's go for a cap :') much better idea.

Comment: Can you get a photo of the second one from the opposite side?

Comment: @Kartman it's a homebrew design, so no schematics unfortunately. I'm still struggling to understand the input stage, but there's a feedback path from output back to what must be the input stage, and this blobby thing seems to connect from the feedback path to something that is probably the VAS

Comment: @winny it's symmetrical, the other side looks about the same! Same shape, about the same colors, and no markings... I will add some more photos in a bit.

Comment: Thanks. Can you measure any resistance across it?

Comment: What are the transistors used? There were a number of 'standard' designs that would be adopted. some of these would come from the likes of Philips/Mullard or from the electronic magazines of the day. The electro looks like an oldPhilips type.

Comment: @winny it shows a resistance that slowly climbs to 40k (takes about 10 seconds), both ways. So my guess would be some kind of capacitor?

Comment: @kartman 2x 2n3055 in the output stage, driven by bfy64/2n2219a resp 2n2219a/bfy64. What looks like the VAS has 2n930 and 2n2219a, and the input stage (?) has bc177 and 2n930, but not as LTP, which I still don't understand

Comment: That’s too high for a PTC of that size. I’m thinking MOV. Can you trace out the schematic around it?

Comment: @winny https://www.crondor.net/~michel/amp.svg right in the middle, C8

Comment: I finally got and built my transistor/component tester, and all it gives me is 1pF capacitance. So maybe it's just a weird form factor for a very small capacitor. Resistance is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Second items looks to be a (Philips) Vishay PTC thermistor like this one but not necessarily this value: https://uk.farnell.com/vishay/ptccl13h321hbe/thermistor-ptc-8r4-20-radial/dp/1187084

Comment: I added more pictures, in particular look at the one from the top. Seems like it's way too thick for a PTC thermistor? Usually those are relatively thin?